# When asked "what's the ruling on a Muslim that doesn't pray" did Sheikh Mohammed al-Ghazali reply "the ruling is YOU invite him to the masjid"?

Tags: salat, source-identification, masjid, islamic-scholar

This was recently posted on [/r/Islam](https://www.reddit.com/r/islam/) on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/islam/comments/7m4zab/question_whats_the_ruling_on_a_muslim_that_doesnt/):

> Question: "What's the ruling on a Muslim that doesn't pray?" Answer: "The ruling is YOU invite him to the masjid!" ~Shk. Muhammad alGhazali (d. 1996)

[Sheikh Mohammed al-Ghazali al-Saqqa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammed_al-Ghazali) appears to be the sheikh in question, but I'm unsure about the reliability of this quote.

**Question**: When asked "what's the ruling on a Muslim that doesn't pray" did Sheikh Mohammed al-Ghazali reply to the effect of "the ruling is YOU invite him to the masjid"?

I found other sources for this online, but nothing reliable.  [TopIslamic.com](http://topislamic.com/30-quotes-imam-ghazali/) writes:

> Shaikh Muhammad Al-Ghazali was asked, “What is the ruling of the one who left prayer?” He replied, “The ruling is for you to take them along with you to the mosque.” Be a caller, not a judge.

[IlmFeed.com](http://ilmfeed.com/30-good-deeds-you-can-do-this-ramadan/) writes:

> A man asked Sheikh Muhammad al Ghazali: “What is the ruling of a
>   person who doesn’t pray?” ‎He said: ‎“The ruling is that you take him
>   with you to the Masjid.”

[Storify.com](https://storify.com/Hasib/invite-before-you-judge-descriptive-vs-prescriptiv) writes:

> "A young man asked Shaikh Mohammad Al Ghazali: "What's the ruling of
>   the person who stops praying?" He replied: "The ruling is to take him
>   with you to the masjid!"

Comment: i think it's hard to find any source for this even with arabic . i saw it in some websites they said , he say it in some of his courses . 
it's very famous in arabic world .

Comment: My findings so far confirm what @MustaphaElbazi said, there's little chance that Sheikh al-Ghazali has quoted it in one of his books, but many people (imams of jumu'ah etc. - like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XW-7faQB_c4) in Arabic-) quote this story. If all you look for is a source then it might be hard to locate unless somebody has a video or tape record of this lesson.

Answer (score 1):

According to a Saudi Sheikh on the Saudi Radio station Mix FM on the 3rd of April 2019 at 10:50am GMT he restated the qu9te and complimented the listener on the saying of Imam Ghazalee : " You should take him to the mosque with you, for the difference between guiding a heart and breaking a heart is a very fine line " more or less to my understanding of it God knows best.

Comment: Please don't confuse imam al-Ghazali with Sheikh al-Ghazali as between both there's a big gap of time it would be helpful if you named that Sheikh who quoted this and added some references/sources to your post.