# What is a Muslim's responsibility towards a non-committed Muslim?

Tags: salat

If a Muslim doesn't pray regularly or neglect other obligatory acts, what is the responsibility of other Muslim's towards him? What if one doesn't perform this responsibility? Is he sinning?

Comment: Sheikh Muhammed al-Ghazaly may Allah have mercy with him would have said: take/invite him to the mosque [When asked whats the ruling on a Muslim that doesn't pray did sheikh Mohammed al-Ghazali reply ...](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45087/when-asked-whats-the-ruling-on-a-muslim-that-doesnt-pray-did-sheikh-mohammed)!

Answer (score 1):

Your responsibility towards a non-committed Muslim is to simply advise him , other than that , you aren't responsible .(ie if he refuses your advice , etc.)

**Resources**:

- [Islam Web](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=182273)  (Arabic)
- [Hadith Portal](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/103)
- [Tafseer Nwawy on advising a fellow Muslim](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=iWFLCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT327&lpg=PT327&dq=%D9%88%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%A7+%D9%86%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86+%D9%80+%D9%88%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%A7+%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%B1+%D9%80+%D9%81%D8%A5%D8%B1%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%81%D9%8A+%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D9%83%D9%81+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B0%D9%89+%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%87%D9%85%D8%8C+%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%85%D8%A7+%D9%8A%D8%AC%D9%87%D9%84%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%87%D9%85+%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87+%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D9%88%D9%84+%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B9%D9%84+%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%B1+%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%AF+%D8%AE%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%81%D8%B9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%B1+%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%A8+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B9+%D9%84%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%85+%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%81+%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87%D9%8A%D9%87%D9%85+%D8%B9%D9%86+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D9%83%D8%B1+%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%81%D9%82+%D9%88%D8%A5%D8%AE%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B5+%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%81%D9%82%D8%A9+%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%B1+%D9%83%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%A9+%D8%B5%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%AE%D9%88%D9%84%D9%87%D9%85+%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B9%D8%B8%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%A9+%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%83+%D8%BA%D8%B4%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%AD%D8%B3%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%A3%D9%86+%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A8+%D9%84%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%85%D8%A7+%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A8+%D9%84%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%87+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D9%8A%D8%B1+%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%87+%D9%84%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%85%D8%A7+%D9%8A%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%87+%D9%84%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%87+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%87+%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B0%D8%A8+%D8%B9%D9%86+%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%A3%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B6%D9%87%D9%85+%D9%88%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1+%D8%B0%D9%84%D9%83+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D9%85+%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D9%88%D9%84+%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B9%D9%84+%D9%88%D8%AD%D8%AB%D9%87%D9%85+%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%82+%D8%A8%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B9+%D9%85%D8%A7+%D8%B0%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%87+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%A3%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A9+%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%B7+%D9%87%D9%85%D9%87%D9%85+%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%89+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AA....%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A9+%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A9+%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89+%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%B1+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A9+%D8%A5%D8%B0%D8%A7+%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%AD+%D8%A3%D9%86%D9%87+%D9%8A%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%84+%D9%86%D8%B5%D8%AD%D9%87+%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%B9+%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%87+%D9%88%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89+%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%87+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%87%D8%8C+%D9%81%D8%A5%D9%86+%D8%AE%D8%B4%D9%8A+%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89+%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%87+%D8%A3%D8%B0%D9%89+%D9%81%D9%87%D9%88+%D9%81%D9%8A+%D8%B3%D8%B9%D8%A9.&source=bl&ots=yPadRhvQFo&sig=bYzfmOABx1QRYgEaqPhZd0oD9Qw&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA5uXamLPdAhWIGuwKHYhTAvUQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)   (Arabic)

Comment: Is this responsibility obligatory upon me? If so, what is prescribed to do if they don't listen?

Comment: @Crimson as far as I understand , you need to atleast try to advise them , if they don't listen then there is no fault upon you if they do something bad afterwards. As for what to do with them , your friendship with them need not be affected , but of course you should avoid joining them in anything that is haram or questionable , maintaining your own worship and steering away from any group activity that doesn't make you comfortable , if they are your friends they would understand that . You are only encouraged to leave them if they are actively trying to drag you into their lifestyle by force

Comment: @Crimson (i.e if they have a significantly bad influence on you ) otherwise , continue your relationship with them as usual and mind your own self .